# Explicit description of primes for which $2$ is a quartic residue?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24697/help-complete-a-proof-of-dirichlet-on-biquadratic-character-of-2) SE question (and the internet more generally), $2$ is a quartic residue modulo a prime $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ if and only if $p$ may be written in the form $a^2 + 64b^2$ for integers $a$ and $b$. Naively, this condition seems a bit unwieldy, and I would like some simple way of telling whether a prime satisfies it. Does such a condition exist?

Comparing the the quadratic case, $2$ is a quadratic residue if and only if $p \equiv \pm 1\pmod{8}$. This feels much nicer and more explicit to me, although I suspect the quartic case may be inherently nastier.

Comment: It will be nastier. A key difference is that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)/\mathbb Q$ is an abelian extension, while the Galois closure of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)/\mathbb Q$ is not.

Comment: @Mathmo123 that's an interesting connection. Could you suggest some reading that might help me understand the relationship between quartic residues and abelianness of the Galois closure?

Comment: It depends on your background in algebraic number theory. $2$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ if and only if $p$ splits in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ as a product of $2$ primes. Similarly $2$ is a quartic residue mod $p$ if and only if $p$ splits in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt[4] 2, i]$. The first case can be classified by class field theory, which (roughly) relates the splitting properties of primes in abelian extensions to Dirichlet characters. A prime splits if and only if a certain character $\chi\colon (\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z)^\times\to \mathbb C^\times$ has $\chi(p ) = 1$...

Comment: But for non-abelian extensions, class field theory doesn't give you anything. [This MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11747/galoisian-sets-of-prime-numbers/12382#12382) is relevant, but it's pretty advanced stuff! But long story short, you can't expect a simple answer like $p \equiv a,b,c \pmod N$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help! Class field theory happens to be one of the next things on my bucket list:)

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A040098

Comment: it is due to Gauss  and can be done by quartic, usually called Biquadratic reciprocity. In Ireland and Rosen (second edition) this is exercises 26, 27, 28 on page 64, method of Dirichlet. Also exercises 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37  on page 136, method of Eisenstein. I see, history in an article by M. J. Collison (1977). On page 133 they spell her name Collision  https://www.jstor.org/stable/41133479